# What is the actuator endpoint to which the togglz library exposes the edit options

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, togglz

I have recently being exploring the togglz library for feature management in Spring Boot application.
In the documentation [here](https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html) , its mentioned that I can use the actuator endpoint

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/togglz/GREETING
```

to edit my features. But what is 'GREETING' here?
I tried with my feature name, but it didn't worked. It's also not mentioned in the documentation either.
Please help me out if someone has used this.

I am using the below dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

PS: I know about the console, but I don't want to use the console, I have to use the endpoint only to toggle the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actuator endpoint only allows you to change the state (i.e. true or false) of an existing feature by that same name. See the code's comment and implementation: https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/2.8.0/spring-boot/starter/src/main/java/org/togglz/spring/boot/actuate/TogglzEndpoint.java#L63